# Using quotes with #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I would like to do something like this:

```
#define OF(k)                                     \
Open("##k##file");
```

That means, that

```
OF(1)
```

must be equivalent to

```
Open("1file");
```

How to do this correctly?

Comment: What do you want OF(hello) to expand to?

Answer (score 6):

```
#define OF(k)                                     \
Open(#k "file");
```

Which makes OF(foo) become `Open("foo" "file")`, which is equivalent to `Open("foofile")`